# jQuery .keyup for every input box on page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set variables as the text a user puts in the input box. So I've set the page up like so:

```
var1 = ""

<input type="text" id="var1">
```

I am trying to set the value of var1 as whatever the user types HOWEVER I have many input boxes set like this. I would prefer not to create a function for each one individually. Any ideas on how to do this for every input box on the page

Edit: sorry for the confusion. I meant I have multiple vars too. So for example I have var1, var2, ect all with their respective input boxes

Comment: Uhm, set var 1 to whatever is typed last, no matter what element it's typed into, or create a new variable for each input ?

Comment: sorry I made an edit to clarify @adeneo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to save the value in an object :

```
var savedValue = {}
$('input').keyup(function(){
    savedValue[this.id] = $(this).val()
})
```

Then you can acces it like that :

```
savedValue.var1
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to set defaults?

Comment: @Charlie, you can do `var savedValue = {var1 : value};` but the name must have the same of your id.

Answer (score 1):

You might not want to store the value in a global variable. And i assume you'd want to store the value separately for each input. so..

```
$('input').on('keyup',function(){
    $(this).data('var1',$(this).val());
})
```

to retrieve it

```
$('input').each(function(){
    var var1 = $(this).data('var1');
    //do something here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('input').bind('keyup', function() { var1 = $(this).val()});` should do it. Not sure if you want all values stored in a single variable if you have a lot though.